# SQLite on Android return wrong result

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having some troubles querying my SQLite DB from my Android APP.

This is the table I'm querying:

```
id | customerCode | invoiceNumber | openAmount | grossAmount
```

and this are the datas:

```
1 | 1 | 1 | -1.00 | -1.00
2 | 1 | 1 | 1.00 | 1.00
3 | 1 | 1 | 10.00 | 10.00
4 | 1 | 2 | 0.00 | 20.00
5 | 1 | 3 | 0.00 | 30.00
```

I'm trying to fetch only the lines which have `openAmount != "0.00"` and the query is:

```
String whereClause = MyTable.CUSTOMER_CODE + " = ? "
                + "and " + MyTable.OPEN_AMOUNT + " != \"0.00\"";

Cursor cur = mDb.query(MyTable.TABLE, null, whereClause, new String[]{customerId}, null, null, null);
```

The result I expect is that the query fetch the first 3 lines from my table, and this is the result I obtain if I query the DB from an external application (like [SQLite Magic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.SQLite.Magic)).

BUT... when I run the query from my Application, I obtain only the line with `openAmount = -1.00`.

I've tried a lot of solutions, like changing the where condition to fetch all the lines, but it seems that querying from my App not reads line `2` and `3`.

I can't figure out a solution. 
A little help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

1. All columns are `TEXT`.
2. It's not relevant how I iterate trhough the
   datas, in fact the cursor altready returns a wrong number of lines.

**EDIT 2**

I'm cycling though the result Cursor, and this is how i do it:

```
    List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
    MyObject obj;

    //initialization of columnsIndex
    //int idx1 = cur.getColumnIndex(columnName);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            obj = new MyObject();
            //set obj data
            list.add(obj);
        } while (cur.moveToNext());

    }
    cur.close();
```

Comment: `The result I expect is that the query fetch the first 3 lines` Your expectations are **wrong**.

Comment: The second parameter of mDb.query() are the columns you wanted to fetch. If this parameter is null, you won't retrieve what you want

Comment: If the second param is `null`, `mDb.query()` fetch all the columns, like `*`

Comment: You need to show us how you are iterating through the cursor....

Comment: **1** - Why are you using TEXT fields where NUMBERS would be more appropriate? **2** - The query returns exactly what you asked: The first line which satisfies your condition.

Comment: **1** - I'm using TEXT because I inherithed the DB, and I've not created it. **2** - And how I can extract all the lines that satisfy my condition?

Comment: **1** - Change it AS SOON AS POSSIBLE. **2** - For TEXT, use the LIKE operator, for NUMBERS use comparison. But you have to **cycle** throught he result set.

Comment: edit: add how I cycle cursor

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:**

```
String whereClause = MyTable.CUSTOMER_CODE + " = ? "
                        + "and " + MyTable.OPEN_AMOUNT + " NOT LIKE '0.00'";
Cursor cur = mDb.query(MyTable.TABLE, null, whereClause, new String[]{customerId}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: stil nothing, the result is the same as before